# Relative legislation and legal consequences

Tags: australia

My exes girlfriends mother accidentally  transferred money  into an old bank account of mine. I Only discontinued use 3weeks ago Due to opening a joint account with my new girlfriend. The account was in arrears and automatically took some of the money. I moved the remaining amount into my current account to avoid further debits being made from the money. My ex has signed into my bank account without my consent, on multiple occasions. She has then provided her mother,  friends and and family court lawyers with information pertaining to my previous account. I have the detailed activity report with dates and times my account was unlawfully accessed, I also have copies of account specific information being provided by these people. I want to know if there are any laws that protect Me and have her reprimanded for the invasion of my privacy And sharing my financial details.

**EDIT:**
We've been separated for over a year and she accessed my account when we first separated as well. I requested her to not log in to my account again and she hadn't up until now. I still have the same account details however.

Comment: When you say "ex", do you mean "ex-wife" or "ex-girlfriend"?

Comment: I'm assuming that "signed into my bank account" occurred through your bank's online web portal. If so, have you taken any action to try to prevent this (such as changing the username and/or password)?

Comment: The first half of your statement doesn't really matter if I understand your question correctly. Can you edit your question to focus on account access by your ex.

Comment: Ex defacto relationship.

Comment: You still haven't said how the transfers were made.  Was this through a web portal?  If so, change your password.  You have a detailed activity report with fraudulent transactions.  Can you prove they were fraudulent?

Answer (score 3):

**How did she access *your* bank account?**

If it was a joint account then it is as much hers as yours and she can treat it as her own.

If it is yours alone, how did she get in? If you gave her the PIN/password then *you* gave her permission to access it. If you didn’t, treat her like any other hacker - notify your bank and the police.